# Show back button in charm settings with my privacy page in windows store apps

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a code which show privacy policy URL in charm settings bar.But what I need is like when user clicks on the privacy policy link it should open another page in charm settings with a back button.How to do the same in the below code

```
 private async void OpenPrivacyPolicy(IUICommand command)
        {     
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://sites.google.com/site/mysite/");

            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
        }
```

Comment: It's easy, replace this code (open URL) with code, that will open another page in Settings Charm.

Comment: I think you are looking for a Flyout, take a look at the [Flyout sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Flyout-sample-258757b3).

Comment: @crea7or well assume I have a XAML page named "Privacy.xaml" and it has a hyperlink.Now I wanna show this page in the settings charm.How will I call this page? and I have written the above code in App.xaml.cs page

Comment: Replace it with: this.Frame.Navigate( typeof( Privacy ) );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the solution,thanks to windows 8.1 Appsetting sample app . First of all add a settingsFlyout XAML page to your project.I added the privacy flyout code in my app's home page like this

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += onCommandsRequested;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested -= onCommandsRequested;
    }
    void onCommandsRequested(SettingsPane settingsPane, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        SettingsCommand defaultsCommand = new SettingsCommand("Privacy", "Privacy",
            (handler) =>
            {
                Privacy sf = new Privacy();
                sf.Show();
            });
        e.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(defaultsCommand);

    }
```

then in my Privacy.xaml page I added the following code

```
 public Privacy()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += SettingsFlyout1_AcceleratorKeyActivated;
        };
        this.Unloaded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated -= SettingsFlyout1_AcceleratorKeyActivated;
        };
    }
    void SettingsFlyout1_AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
    {
        // Only investigate further when Left is pressed
        if (args.EventType == CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.SystemKeyDown &&
            args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Left)
        {
            var coreWindow = Window.Current.CoreWindow;
            var downState = CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down;


            bool menuKey = (coreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Menu) & downState) == downState;
            bool controlKey = (coreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control) & downState) == downState;
            bool shiftKey = (coreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift) & downState) == downState;

            if (menuKey && !controlKey && !shiftKey)
            {
                args.Handled = true;
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for all the help everyone! And this code works!If anyone facing difficulty just hit me ;)